# How can I pass a variable in a decorator to function's argument in a decorated function?

Tags: python, decorator

I am in progress to learn Python. Hopefully someone points me to correct way.
This is what I'd like to do below:

```
def decorate(function):
    def wrap_function(*args, **kwargs):
        str = 'Hello!'  # This is what I want
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_function

@decorate
def print_message():
    # I'd like to pass 'str' as mentioned above
    # to any functions' argument like below:
    print(str)  # 'str' is same as above
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can't pass it as its own name, but you can add it to the keywords.

```
def decorate(function):
    def wrap_function(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['str'] = 'Hello!'
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_function

@decorate
def print_message(*args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['str'])
```

Alternatively you can name its own argument:

```
def decorate(function):
    def wrap_function(*args, **kwargs):
        str = 'Hello!'
        return function(str, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_function

@decorate
def print_message(str, *args, **kwargs):
    print(str)
```

Class method:

```
def decorate(function):
    def wrap_function(*args, **kwargs):
        str = 'Hello!'
        args.insert(1, str)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_function

class Printer:
    @decorate
    def print_message(self, str, *args, **kwargs):
        print(str)
```

Comment: Note that the first solution is also achieved by using `functools.partial()` (but from version 2.6 only). The same module also offers the `wraps()` function which can be used with decorators to maintain the name and the doc of the original function.

Comment: @RedGlyph: why using `functools.partial()` from version 2.6 only? the documentation say nothing about it except that functools module is new in pyhton 2.5.

Comment: Thanks to Tor Valamo. Alternative solution is clear for me. But how about if the decorated function is an instance method? The instance method's argument should be something like: `def print_message(str, self, *args, **kwargs):` Is this correct? Thanks again.

Comment: switch self and str. def print_message(self, str, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: in this case `def print_message(self, str, *args, **kwargs)`, `self` gives me `Hello!` from `wrap_function`, and `str` gives me something like class object.

Comment: yes, that's because the args list contains 'self' as the first item. you can fix it with args.insert(1, str) and then return function(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: now everything seems clear for me. thanks again Tor Valamo :D happy holidays!

Comment: @Japboy: i don't know if you noticed but `print_message` don't need extra `*args` and `**kwargs` arguments so don't declare so you function if you don't need it. imho a decorator is more powerful the more the decorated function is unaware of it

Comment: @mg: you're right, 2.6 was for the function above in a table. It should read "2.5".

Answer (score 19):

If you want the argument to be "optionally-injected", only in case the function actually takes it, use something like this:

```
import inspect

def decorate(func):
    def wrap_and_call(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'str' in inspect.getargspec(func).args:
            kwargs['str'] = 'Hello!'
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_and_call

@decorate
def func1(str):
    print "Works! - " + str

@decorate
def func2():
    print "Should work, also."
```

Comment: Note that getargspec is deprecated. For Python3, use [getfullargspec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec).

Comment: Alternatively: 'str' in inspect.signature(func).parameters