# "Push" attribute from decorator to decorated function in Python

Tags: python, decorator

Some basic question from beginner. Is there a way to "push" attribute to a decorated function not using function arguments ?

```
import sys
from functools import wraps


def decorator_(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc():
        func.some_attr = 'some_attr'
        func()
    return newfunc

@decorator_
def decorated_function():
    # ??? access some_attr ???
    print some_attr

def main():
    decorated_function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it's exactly what you want, but this is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965607/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-in-a-decorator-to-functions-argument-in-a-decorated-f

It does use arguments, but in a way that is compatible with what you are trying to accomplish, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, this is a useful link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the attribute on `new_func` instead, you can access it simply as `decorated_function.some_attr`:

```
def decorator_(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc():
        newfunc.some_attr = 'some_attr'
        func()
    return newfunc

@decorator_
def decorated_function():
    print(decorated_function.some_attr)
```

Otherwise, `wraps` makes the original function available as `decorated_function.__wrapped__` in Python 3:

```
def decorator_(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc():
        func.some_attr = 'some_attr'
        func()
    return newfunc

@decorator_
def decorated_function():
    print(decorated_function.__wrapped__.some_attr)
```

In Python 2, the `__wrapped__` is not set by `wraps`, so we need to set it up manually:

```
def decorator_(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc():
        func.some_attr = 'some_attr'
        func()
    newfunc.__wraps__ = func
    return newfunc
```

However, this sounds like an XY problem; if you want to pass a value to the `decorated_function` you should let `decorator_` pass it as an argument instead.

Comment: Thanks, this works. It's  a bit off what I was expecting in a way that I have to refer to attribute as func_name.attr instead of just attr. But I'm a bit confused that filmor's solution works too. It looks like two methods to do the same. There are probably some hidden stones somewhere which I can not see ?

Comment: @psb actually you'd want to do **neither** of these. filmor's solution sets a *global variable* in the module that defined `decorated_function`

Comment: Could you please point me to some reasons why ? In a some very common words.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I was too quick to say that your answer works for me. Looks like your answer works in  Python3 only ?

Comment: @psb ah, it is because `wraps` doesn't set `__wrapped__` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you use Python 2 or 3 you can inject variables into the `globals` of a function like this:

#### Python 2

```
func.func_globals["some_attr"] = "some_value"
```

#### Python 3

```
func.__globals__["some_attr"] = "some_value"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. And it feels like the solution I was looking for but I'm a bit confused that Antti's solution works too. It looks like two methods to do the same. There are probably some hidden stones somewhere which I can not see ?

Comment: After inspecting Antti's answer and comment - is there any way to inject variable to function "locals" ? That would be preferable way.