# How do i pass a variable in a function to a decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I have a function that defines a variable inside of it called animal.
I also have a decorator for that function, but it needs the variable that's defined in the original function.

Either I need the animal variable from the original function, or I need to somehow pass the model_data variable from the decorator into the original function. Any input?

Here is the code:

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["GET", "PUT", "DELETE"])
@parse_model_data
def base_animal(request, model_id):

    try:
        animal = Animal.objects.get(pk=model_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return json_error(error="No animal found for id: %s" % model_id)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return json_success(model=animal)

    if request.method == "DELETE":
        animal.delete()
        return json_success("Animal deleted.")

    if request.method == "PUT":
       animal.save()
       return json_success()
```

Here is the decorator function:

```
def parse_model_data(originalFunction):
  def parse(*args, **kwargs):
        request = args[0]
        model_data = request.get_json_body()
        if not model_data:
          return json_error("no json body detected")
        model_data = Animal.parse_model_data(model_data)
        for attr, value in model_data.items():
            setattr(animal, attr, value)
        return originalFunction(*args, **kwargs)

return parse
```

Comment: Make it part of the method signature so it's present on *args.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Make it a part of the method signature for the original function? And by it, do you mean model_data, or animal?

Comment: CHeck [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965607/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-in-a-decorator-to-functions-argument-in-a-decorated-f), it might help

Comment: Yes, I did see that, I want to do the opposite. I want to pass an argument TO the decorator from the original function.

Comment: The decorator magic works based on the same arguments of the original function so as I said add an arg to the signature or... try to add the value to your request object ;-).

Answer (score 3):

A decorator is not meant for this. It cannot access an object created inside the function because that object does not exist yet when the decorated function, `parse`, is called.

It seems what you need here is a plain simple function.

```
def parse(animal, request):
    model_data = request.get_json_body()
    if not model_data:
      return json_error("no json body detected")
    model_data = Animal.parse_model_data(model_data)
    for attr, value in model_data.items():
        setattr(animal, attr, value)

@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["GET", "PUT", "DELETE"])
def base_animal(request, model_id):
    try:
        animal = Animal.objects.get(pk=model_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return json_error(error="No animal found for id: %s" % model_id)

    # Here we use our parse function
    # It cannot be called before that point since animal did not exist
    parse(animal, request)

    ...
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought that a normal function was the way to go, but the task i was assigned was to "implement a decorator function" for this purpose.

Comment: Maybe what was meant is to have a decorator use the model_id to fetch the animal and inject it as argument. Would that make sense?